# Is there a way to print the content from the API to the localhost server?

Tags: java, html, spring, api, rest

I'm trying to learn spring and at the same time build a small project and I encountered a problem. Everything works as it should, but I can't figure out how to make use of the API's method content that is printed in my Eclipse Console.

In my controller I have all the information required to use the specific method of the API. I mapped the URL using **"@GetMapping("/seasons")** and I'm using a code snippet from an online API(with key). And in the VIEW folder(basically where I keep the JSP files, example: seasons.jsp) I am trying to retrieve data from the response of the API.

This is the response of the API: "`{"get":"seasons","parameters":[],"errors":[],"results":10,"response":[2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021]}`"

UPDATE:

Here is some code for refference:

```
    @GetMapping("/seasons")
public String seasons(Model theModel) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    List<Integer> SeasonsList = new ArrayList<>();

    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create("https://api-formula-1.p.rapidapi.com/seasons"))
            .header("x-rapidapi-host", "api-formula-1.p.rapidapi.com")
            .header("x-rapidapi-key", "5a6f44fa10msh40be2be8d20bc5bp18a190jsnb4478dcbc8f1")
            .method("GET", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
            .build();
    HttpResponse<String> response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    
    JSONObject seasonsObject = new JSONObject(response.body());
    for(int i = 0; i < seasonsObject.length(); i++) {
        JSONArray object = seasonsObject.getJSONArray("response");
        for(int j = 0 ; i < object.length(); j++) {
            SeasonsList.add(object.getInt(j));
            
        }
        System.out.println(object);
    }
    
    theModel.addAttribute("theSeasons", SeasonsList);
    return "seasons";
}
```

And the HTML file:

```
<html xmlns:th ="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>


<title>The Formula 1 Seasons are</title>


</head>

<body>
 <p th:text ="'The seasons are:  ' + ${theSeasons}"/>

</body>


</html>
```

The thing that I want is to show  "The seasons are : 2012, 2013, 2014..etc.

**And I get an error in console : "org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[10] not found."**

Please let me know if you need any detail from my project.

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Ok sorry, I'll delete my post.

Comment: No need to delete. Just [edit] it.

Comment: Hope It's okay right now. If there is a lack of detail somewhere, please let me know so I give more of it.

Comment: `for (int j = 0 ; i < object.length(); j++)`

Comment: I got it, saw the error, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner loop uses the wrong loop variable and moves `j` past the end of the array:

```java
// Don't do this
for (int j = 0 ; i < object.length(); j++) { // Comparing "i"; compare "j" instead

// Do this
for (int j = 0 ; j < object.length(); j++) {
```

It's not clear why there needs to be an *outer* loop, though; you're pulling a known property from a known response; there's no reason for the outer loop AFAICT.